# The system is out of resources when building Apache FOP

Tags: java, out-of-memory

When trying to build Apache FOP by ant on the command line, it complains:

```
[javac] The system is out of resources.
[javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
[javac]     ...
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
```

I don't understand. I have enough RAM, how can the system run out of resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give more memory to your JVM. e.g. the below allocates 512Mb to the JVM.

```
javac -Xmx512m ...
```

The Java virtual machine runs with a fixed *maximum* memory size. For memory-intensive operations you need to increase this appropriately. `-Xmx` specifies the maximum amount of memory the JVM will take. `-Xms` specifies the amount of memory the JVM allocates *on start-up*.

There's a nice summary of options [here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control).

Note: Given the above occurs via Ant, you may need to increase the memory available to Ant (e.g. `set ANT_OPTS=-Xms256M -Xmx512M`), and/or the memory available to your `javac` process if that's being forked as a separate executable.

Comment: Thanks! export ANT_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M" finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

the size of your system memory is only half of the story,  the JVM  allocates a memory chunck as a  heap space  when it starts up.  the java compiler as a java application has only this amount of memory to work with

you can set the heap size for the java compiler yourself with this option

```
javac     -J-Xms<size>m
```

see the complete  switches sets [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)